# Closed form for a class of recursive functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, polynomials, recurrence-relations, recursion

Suppose we define a class of functions $f_n$ (with domain $\mathbb{N}^n$ without $0$) as follows:
$$
f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{cases} 1, & x_1=1\\
x_1, & x_2=1\\
\,\vdots & \,\vdots\\
x_{n-2}, & x_{n-1} = 1 \\
x_{n-1}, & x_n = 1\\
f_n(x_1-1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)  + \ldots + f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n-1), &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
For clarity, the *otherwise* case returns the value
$$ f_n(x_1-1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) + f_n(x_1,x_2-1,\ldots,x_n) + \ldots + f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n-1). $$

We can see that $f_1(x) = 1$ for all $x$, and from the similarity to binomial coefficients we get that $$f_2(x,y) = {{x+y-1}\choose{x-1}}. $$
It may be helpful to observe that $f_n$ has a similar recursive definition to that of the multinomial coefficient.

The question is:

> Is there a closed form formula of $f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ for any given $n$, and what is it given that one exists?

**Clarification:**
Evaluate cases in order from top to bottom. For example, if both $x_n = 1$ and $x_{n+k} = 1$, the case for $x_n$ takes precedent.

Comment: Your cases are not mutually exclusive. What if $x_1=1$ *and* $x_2=1$?

Comment: It'll give the same output, since $x_2 = 1$ means we return $x_1$, but $x_1=1$ and so we still output $1$.

Comment: Fair. What if $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, and $x_3=1$? Is it $1$ or $2$?

Comment: This is a good point. Go from top to bottom, so in this case it returns 1.

Comment: If $x_1, \cdots, x_n \geq 2$, then $$f_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{d_1 = 0}^{x_1-2} \cdots \widehat{\sum_{d_k=0}^{x_k-2}} \cdots \sum_{d_n=0}^{x_n-2} B(d_1, \cdots, x_k-2, \cdots, d_n) (x_{k-1} - d_{k-1})$$ where $B(d_1,\cdots,d_n)=\frac{(d_1+\cdots+d_n)!}{d_1!\cdots d_n!}$ is the multinomial. I am not sure if this even simplifies further...

Comment: Can you clarify the notation you used? In particular, what is the hat on the $x_k-2$ sum; is $x_0$ to be interpreted as $x_n$ (i.e. $x_{k-1}$ for $k=1$); in the multinomial, you use $x_k - 2$, is this the $k$-th input?